# youtube iframe api - channel link in logo

Tags: iframe, hyperlink, youtube, youtube-channels

I am using the Youtube Iframe API to embed Youtube videos on a website. The client asked to have instead of the video URL as href of the Youtube Logo (the one seen on the bottom right corner) the URL of the video channel (the Youtube Channel where the video was posted).

The client claims to have seen this before on some other website, but it could not provide an example .. My guess was to try looking for some player parameters (https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters) but there is no such a parameter.

I read through the rest of the API Docs and googled the issue, but had no luck so far.

Did anyone manage to do this before? Is it somehow possible?